# AspNet Boilerplate: Hangfire Queues

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, hangfire

I'm trying to use [Hangfire Queues](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-queues.html) in my AspNet Zero project.

I configured the backend to only process specific queues as illustrated in this example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHangfireServer(options =>
    {
        options.Queues = new[] { "alpha", "beta", "default" };
    });
}
```

However, applying the `QueueAttribute` to the `Execute()` method, does not seem to specify which queue the job should be processed on. The entry in the Hangfire database is always `default`.

```
public class TestJob : BackgroundJob<int>, ITransientDependency
{
    [Queue("alpha")]
    public override void Execute(int number)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

The job is enqueued according to the ABP documentation:

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IBackgroundJobManager _backgroundJobManager;

    public MyService(IBackgroundJobManager backgroundJobManager)
    {
        _backgroundJobManager = backgroundJobManager;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        _backgroundJobManager.Enqueue<TestJob, int>(42);
    }
}
```

How would one specify the job queue when enqueuing it?

Comment: try IBackgroundJobClient of hangfire to fire up the jobs

Comment: Did you try the **Static method"" like this ?
`BackgroundJob.Enqueue<TestJob>(x => x.Execute(123))`

Comment: @RajithaKithuldeniya: Yep, that's the answer given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cannot specify the queue name using ABP as the framework will use dependency injection to resolve the type `IBackgroundJob<TArgs>` int the [HangfireBackgroundJobManager](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.HangFire.AspNetCore/Hangfire/HangfireBackgroundJobManager.cs).

When using DI, the `interface` must be decorated with the `[Queue("your_queue"]` attribute, and we don't have access to the `IBackgroundJob` interface at this level for obvious reasons.

I solved this by using Hangfire directly. The code:

```
public interface ITestJob : ITransientDependency
{
    [Queue("alpha")]
    public void Execute(int number);
}
```

```
public class TestJob : ITestJob, ITransientDependency
{
    public void Execute(int number)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

```
using Hangfire;

public class MyService
{
    public MyService()
    {
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        BackgroundJob.Enqueue<ITestJob>(x => x.Execute(42));
    }
}
```